# Dynamic DNS Redirecting to Router

Tags: router, dynamic-dns, noip

I am trying to create a website and I am using my PC to run XAMPP and noip to get a domain, but whenever I go to my noip website, it redirects to my router configuration page. My router is Calix 844E.

Comment: You need port forwarding to your website.

Comment: Also, if you are trying this from inside your network you need to be aware of Hairpin NAT - if your router does not support it, this won't work from within your LAN.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In order for the website to be visible from the internet, you need to forward the traffic you send to your domain to the correct port of your PC. Only after that it is addressable from the Internet. If it is a standard http website you want to open, you will probably need to forward the external 8080 port from your router to the internal 8080 port of your PC.